# unable to work with cp1256 in perl

Tags: perl

I have a simple script for counting words, it count only english words and doesn't see the arabic ones encoded in cp-1256 which is my main concern. I'm working on windows 8
Here is a sample of the file:

Textإذا اعتبرنا جوجول وتشيكوف هما رئدا القصة في العالم فإننا نعتبر الدكتور يوسف إدريس هو أمير القصة القصيرة لدي العرب إذ حقق للقصة القصيرة في مصر والعالم العربي نقلة نوعية من حيث البناء والفكرة والطرح، كان ذلك بين أواخر الخمسينيات وطوال الستينيات ورغم التطور النوعي الفارق الذي أحدثه فيما يتعلق بفكرة التحديث،
إلا أن قصصه كانت لصيقة بالحياة ومتقاطعة مع قطاع عظيم من البشر المهمشين، خاصة من خلال مجموعاته القصصية «بيت من لحم» و«لغة الأي آي» و«أرخص ليالي» وقد ولد يوسف إدريس «زي النهارده» من عام 1927 في «البيروم» بمحافظة الشرقية.
وليوسف إدريس نحو عشرين مجموعة قصصية وخمس روايات كان منها «الحرام» و«قاع المدينة» «والنداهة» وكانت أعماله القصصية قد ترجمت للكثير من اللغات الأخري ومنها نحو 65 قصة ترجمت للروسية،
وكان يوسف إدريس قد كتب للأهرام سلسلة من المقالات التي صدرت مجمعة من كتاب يحمل عنوان «فقر الفكر وفكر الفقر» وكان قد حصل علي جائزة الدولة التشجيعية عام 1966،
وقيل إن اسمه كان مدرجاً ضمن المرشحين لجائزة نوبل عام 1988 والتي حظي بها نجيب محفوظ، وكان له في ذلك هجوم شهير.
وليوسف إدريس عدد من المسرحيات كان منها «الفرافير» و«المخططين» و«البهلوان» و«اللحظة الحرجة» و«المهزلة الأرضية» و«الجنس الثالث».
Text

```
while (<>) {
    @words = split(/\W+/);
    foreach $word (@words) {
        $count{$word}++;
    }
}
foreach $word (sort by_count keys %count) {
     print "$word occurs $count{$word} times\n";
}
sub by_count {
    $count{$b} <=> $count{$a};
}
```

I had an old script with these on top of it and was working fine but now it is not

```
use win32;
use POSIX 'locale_h';
use locale;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the encoding of the input stream.

```
use open IN => ':encoding(cp1256)';   # For "script file"
binmode STDIN, ':encoding(cp1256)';   # For "script <file"
```

If you also want to output cp1256, you can replace the above two with

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(cp1256)';   # All input and output
```

Answer (score 0):

just for the sake of knowledge I changed the print statement to do sorting

```
foreach $word (sort by_count keys %count) {
printf "%5d \t %s\n", $count{$word}, $word;
```

thanks